# Flutter Windows access other application information

Tags: windows, flutter, dart, desktop-application

I want to build windows app with Flutter but I have to access Spotify apps variables. Like now playing, is playing, current song level etc etc.

How can I achieve this? If I cant do this function with Flutter, what should I search about?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [dio](https://pub.dev/packages/dio) for communicating with [Spotify API](https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/web-api/).

Comment: Not like this. I have to access direct local.